# AngularJS form gets pristine but still submitted

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

According to the source of AngularJS (1.3.15), the [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)'s method `$setPristine()` resets the forms `$submitted` status to false:

```
  form.$setPristine = function() {
    $animate.setClass(element, PRISTINE_CLASS, DIRTY_CLASS + ' ' + SUBMITTED_CLASS);
    form.$dirty = false;
    form.$pristine = true;
    form.$submitted = false;
    forEach(controls, function(control) {
      control.$setPristine();
    });
  };
```

The problem is that after submitting and [calling this method inside a controller](http://plnkr.co/edit/uHm8UmUCrIls5XbkSoGS?p=preview), the form reverts to `$submitted = false`. Is that expected or a bug?

Comment: Related to your concern I believe - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/8056

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this behavior is that the reset button does not have type="button" or type="reset" attribute and therefore it behaves as a submit button by default. So the ng-click that sets the form to pristine actually set $submitted to false correctly, but immediately afterwards, the form is submitted again.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
this.data = {
name: ''
};

this.reset = function(form) {
this.data.name = '';
form.$setPristine();
};

});
```

HTML Page:

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
<title>form.$submitted</title>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
 <form name="form" novalidate>
  <input name="name" ng-model="ctrl.data.name" placeholder="Name" required   />
  <input type="submit" />
  <button type="button" class="button" ng-click="ctrl.reset(form)">Reset</button>
</form>

<pre>

 Pristine: {{form.$pristine}}

 Submitted: {{form.$submitted}}

</pre>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kRxEVu?p=preview

Hope this is the one that you have wanted

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10006#issuecomment-62640975

Comment: Indeed, a `<button type=submit>` (which is the default type for buttons) or `<input type=submit>` will trigger the `submit` event *after* the `click` event. AngularJS handles the `submit` event by setting `form.$submitted` to true, reverting what was done inside the controller.

Comment: also annoying when you use `button[type=submit]` and `form[ng-submit="form.$valid && submit()"]` syntax

Answer (score 2):

You can reset the form after submit by adding $setUntouched() & $setPristine() to the form name after submitting the form OR on success of your Ajax request. Eg:-

```
<form name="userDetailsForm"
      ng-submit="addUserDetails(userDetailsForm.$valid)"
      novalidate>

   <div class="field name-field">
      <input class="input" type="text" name="name" ng-model="form.data.name" required placeholder="First Name + Last Name" />
      <div ng-if="userDetailsForm.$submitted || userDetailsForm.name.$touched" ng-messages="signupForm.name.$error">
         <div ng-message="required">You did not enter your name</div>        
      </div>
   </div>

   <input type="submit" value="Add Details" class="btn btn-default" />

</form>


$scope.addUserDetails = function(valid) {
    if(!valid) return;

    //Your Ajax Request

    $scope.userDetailsForm.$setUntouched();                         
    $scope.userDetailsForm.$setPristine();
};
```

Comment: I didn't know using `$setUntouched()` would automatically set all input fields to `$untouched` & remove all `ng-touched` classes. Good info! Thanks!